# sed substitute the specific sub-str which is matched by regex

Tags: sed

I want to substitute '/' with '$' in a sub string. just as below:

```
{"url":"www.xxx.com/a/b/x/", "title":"hello world", "type":"c/python/perl", "content":"Just use sed"}
```

I want to change sub string '**c/python/perl**' to '**c$python$perl**', whats the elegant sed solution

can i use back reference match c/python/perl with '\1'， then do something with '\1'?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below sed command and don't need to  use a capturing group.

```
sed 's~c/python/perl~c$python$perl~' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '{"url":"www.xxx.com/a/b/x/", "title":"hello world", "type":"c/python/perl", "content":"Just use sed"}' | sed 's~c/python/perl~c$python$perl~'
{"url":"www.xxx.com/a/b/x/", "title":"hello world", "type":"c$python$perl", "content":"Just use sed"}
```

**Update:**

```
$ echo '{"url":"www.xxx.com/a/b/x/", "title":"hello world", "type":"c/python/perl", "content":"Just use sed"}' | awk -F, -v OFS="," '{gsub(/\//,"$",$3)}1'
{"url":"www.xxx.com/a/b/x/", "title":"hello world", "type":"c$python$perl", "content":"Just use sed"}
```

Comment: thanks first. But the "type" field maybe other string, like 'java/c++'. I need a general solution.

Comment: does the fields are same? like first would beurl then title then type like that.

Comment: e, i know the awk solution . i just want know can i do something with back reference \1 in sed.

Comment: BUt you're not sure whether the value contains two or one forward slash. Am i correct?

Comment: @augusto you mean this `sed -r 's/^(.*\"type\":\")(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)(\".*)$/\1\2$\3$\4\5/g'`

Comment: e... "c/python/perl/java" not work;  number of '/' in 'type' not sure

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the back-reference from `sed` as an argument of a bash function. However, they say here: [using command substitution inside a sed script, with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355443/using-command-substitution-inside-a-sed-script-with-arguments), that `sed` won't execute any command.

Still, you can do with `perl` using `e` modifier of the regex:

```
echo '{"url":"www.xxx.com/a/b/x/", "title":"hello world", "type":"c/python/perl", "content":"Just use sed"}' \
    | perl -pe 's/(?<="type":")([^"]*)/`echo -n $1 | tr "\/" "\$"`/e'
```

Comment: is there a solution like below:  sed 's/\(reg\)/;s/\//$/g'

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Please explain more.

Comment: i mean : cat \1 | sed 's/\//$/g'  
like this

Comment: You better mean: `echo \1 | tr '/' '$'`. This is not possible with `sed` according to the linked page as sed won't execute external `tr` (or `sed` in your example) command. That's why I used perl and called external `tr` command from there to show it is possible with perl having very similar call to `sed`.

Comment: Actually instead of `sed` you type `perl -pe` and you have basically the same thing with better regexes and more possibilities including your requirement.